# Pandas Specific Pivot of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to reshape a given `DataFrame`

```
   ts type  value1  value2
0   1  foo      10      16
1   1  bar      11      17
2   2  foo      12      18
3   2  bar      13      19
4   3  foo      14      20
5   3  bar      15      21
```

into the following shape:

```
     foo           bar
  value1 value2 value1 value2
1     10     16     11     17
2     12     18     13     19
3     14     20     15     21
```

I know how to do this programatically, this is not the point. But I for the life of me can't find the proper pandas method to do this efficiently.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
df.set_index(['type','ts']).unstack(0).swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

```
type    bar     foo
    value1  value2  value1  value2
ts              
1   11  17  10  16
2   13  19  12  18
3   15  21  14  20
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer! the `swaplevel(...).sort_index(...)` part was what I was missing. Using that I found a perhaps slightly shorter version: `df.pivot(index='ts', columns='type').swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)`

Comment: yes. Pivot is another way to go about it.